# Can you create a custom jQuery library build?

Tags: javascript, jquery, customization

We have a small javascript project that will be using a handful of jQuery selectors, but we don't by any means need the full jQuery package (i.e. effects). Is there any way to get a custom build of the jQuery library?

Comment: I have written an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224539/2342537

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question was asked before this answer was available - but I feel the question is still relevant.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-your-own-custom-jquery/

http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

Hope others find these links as helpful as I have.

**Update**
Depending on how minimal you want to go you could make your own library, I've used this as a starting concept before:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-first-javascript-library--net-26796

Source code available here: https://github.com/andrew8088/dome

Comment: This in not an acceptable answer, it only contains links to external sites. Please read this for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Good point, however every answer for this question involves an external link.

Comment: Having external links is not the problem, the problem is that there is nothing else. Also, other answers being bad is not an excuse :)

Answer (score 6):

Then you might be intersted in [Sizzle selector engine](http://sizzlejs.com/) (also used by jQuery for its selector mechanism).

Comment: I think that will do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can get source from github http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Git and modify buildfile (makefile or build.xml, depends on build system you will be using). For apache ant (build.xml) just remove files you don't need from list in the jquery target. Of course this will not handle internal jquery requirements for you, so resulting build can be broken.

Comment: Makes sense. I probably only need selectors, so I'm going with @sAc's answer, but this will be handy to know for the future. Thanks!

Comment: I did end up trying this, just for the fun of it, and it's really easy, though a little scary. Unfortunately, cutting out effects, offset, and dimensions only saves about 3k minified/gzipped. Cutting out more will take some testing to make sure it's safe.