# Customizing Minified version of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two JQuery Plugins such as nice scroll & wselect which requires support of latest **jquery-1.10.4.js**;

I want minified JQuery to support Scroll bar & Select Option UIs..

In this  [Jquery link ,](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.4&components=1111000000100010000000000000000000) I am not sure which options to be selected to download minified version for above requirement.

Currently the size of jquery is Huge

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.4.js"></script>
```

Nice Scroll : [find here](http://jquery-plugins.net/nicescroll-jquery-plugin-for-better-scroll-on-desktop-and-mobile)

wSelect : [find here](https://github.com/websanova/wSelect)

I need minified version of jquery-1.10.4.js to support Nicescroll and wSelect as well. (atleast less than 50KB)

Could you please help ?

Comment: I recommend [Grunt](http://example.com) for that with concat and uglify tasks.

Comment: @logan could you clarify? What exactly do you need to customize in jQuery? Also, maybe explain why jQuery v2 doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Christophe : I want minified JQuery to support Scroll bar & Select Option UIs.. (edited question accordingly)

Comment: The link you've posted is for jQuery UI and the modules included in that. What you need is to just get the minified version of jQuery, not jQuery UI.

Comment: @adeneo : yes, i need minified version. jquery-1.10.2.min.js is available but it is still 90KB. is there any leight weight js available ?

Comment: Nope, it is 90kb, and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you create a custom jQuery library build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143195/can-you-create-a-custom-jquery-library-build)

Comment: @Quentin : its not duplicate. i asked what options to be selected to create minified version

Comment: There are no options, that's jQuery UI, not the same thing.

Comment: @logan jQuery != jQuery UI. You need jQuery, the link you posted is for jQuery UI.

Comment: @logan — You said you wanted a version of jQuery that is smaller then the minified version.

Comment: @Quentin : yes. but it shows lot of options to customize. i need to know which one to be selected ?

Comment: How hard can it be, the page with the options are for ***jQuery UI***, which is not jQuery, but an addon for jQuery.

Comment: @logan — Which "it"? There are several links on the question I marked as duplicate. There is also the jQuery UI page you found (which has nothing to do with the problem you are asking about since jQuery UI is a library that *uses* jQuery and is not jQuery itself). Whichever one (assuming you are talking about the links on the duplicate question) you are talking about - we are not going to read the source code of your plugins to figure out which bits of jQuery they depend on, you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: Alright , I will go with jquery-1.10.2.min.js . Thanks all for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one: `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`

Your link is for jQuery UI, which neither of your plugins require.

Comment: i tried it already.. its still 90 kb; i want leight weight file

Comment: @logan That link is 37.6 KB. Don't use jQuery if you cant life with its file size.

Comment: I just checked & saved in notepad it shows 92.0 KB exactly. please give as attachment if any mismatch

Comment: @logan If the server sends it to the browser its gzipped, resulting in 37.6 KB. And that is only for the first request, after that its cached in the browser.

Comment: can you share minified page link to look at ? (not only downloadlink)\

Comment: @logan That is the minified version i linked. Open the Chrome developer tools or Firebug and check the size in the network tab.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45593/discussion-between-logan-and-darthmaim)